# Move Visual Studio Code minimap to the left side?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to move the minimap in Visual Studio Code to the left side of the screen?

I have looked all throughout the documentation and cannot find an option for it.

Answer (score 6):

Moving the minimap to the left was added in v1.20:
[minimap position](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_20#_display-minimap-to-the-left)

```
 "editor.minimap.side": "left"
```

Comment: note: VS code no longer requires you to type this. Just go to file → preferences → settings, and then type "minimap" to pull up the minimap settings. Then pick either left or right for "Editor › Minimap: Side" using the handy dandy GUI drop down.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can flip what you are trying to achieve: Menu Bar | View > Move Side Bar Right

Answer (score 0):

### Minimap.Side Added to MS Code

The option to move the Minimap to the left or right side of the screen has been added. See this from the release notes:

[Display minimap to the left](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_20#_display-minimap-to-the-left):

There is a new setting, `editor.minimap.side`, which can be configured to render the minimap (code outline) on the left.

### STEPS

1. Open the Command Palette (⇧⌘P on macOS)
2. Search for and open User Settings
3. See the Default Settings document is open
4. Find the property `"editor.minimap.side": "right",`
5. Hover your mouse over the property to see the edit icon appear
6. Click the edit icon to edit the property (in the right panel)
7. Set property to `"left"` or `"right"`
8. **Save** your changes

Comment: Hmmm... seems similar to the answer from the day before.